# Calling invalidateLayout on UICollectionView With Self-Sizing Cells Complains About All Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a `UICollectionView` with a few different types of cells and am using Auto Layout to use self-sizing cells. To accomplish this, I am setting `estimatedItemSize` on my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and ensuring the constraints in each of the cells is correct (so I am **not** using the `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` method). The first time the collection view loads, everything looks correct and I get no errors in the logs. Debug View Hierarchy doesn't show any issues either.

In one of the sections, there is a cell that has radio buttons and can cause the height of the content to change based on which radio button is selected. In order to resize the cell after tapping a button, I call `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`.

When this occurs, I get about 3000 lines of logs in the console complaining about broken constraints. It is seemingly complaining about every single constraint present in the cell that was adjusted. However, everything on the screen seems to look exactly how I would want it afterwards, and opening the Debug View Hierarchy doesn't show any issues.

Is this just a product of calling invalidateLayout when Auto Layout is involved? One of the constraints it is complaining about is the the height from the `estimatedItemSize`, so maybe that is what's causing all of this? Maybe it tries to lay out the view using the estimatedItemSize first and then realizes it should be treated as self-sizing?

Calling `reloadData` instead seems to work just fine, except it leads to other undesirable behavior and shouldn't need to be used as the underlying data hasn't changed.

Comment: Instead of `reloadData`, can you do an empty `performBatchUpdates`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried doing an empty `performBatchUpdates` and it didn't seem to do anything. The cell remains at the previous height and doesn't resize.

Comment: Oh well. The problem is that I don't believe self-sizing flow layout cells even exist, so it's hard for me to help.

Comment: @BrianSchrameck - try to put together a [mre] ... tough to offer help in the abstract.

Comment: @DonMag yeah, I will definitely do that once I have some extra time. In the meantime I'm just moving forward with what I've got because it works fine except for the warnings in the logs.